# Alternating Series sum up to $99$ terms is $>0.5$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Prove that $$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\cdots \cdots \cdots -\frac{1}{99}+\frac{1}{100}>0.2$$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write series as $$\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots \cdots +\frac{1}{50}\bigg)-\bigg(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\cdots \cdots +\frac{1}{99}\bigg)$$

Now How can i solve after that, Help Required, Thanks

Comment: Do you mean 0.2 or 0.5?

Comment: @HenningMakholm As the LHS is $\approx 0.31$, I supposeit should be $0.2$

Comment: Might be easier to rewrite the LHS to $\frac 22 H_{50} - H_{100} +1 $.

Comment: I can't understand why the OP doesn't answer direct questions asked to him. -1

Comment: To  DonAntonio  actually it does not strike in my mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\left(\frac12-\frac13\right)+\left(\frac14-\frac15\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac1{98}-\frac1{99}\right)+\frac1{100}>\left(\frac12-\frac13\right)+\left(\frac14-\frac15\right)=0.21\overline 6$$

Comment: (+1) I was just about to give a very similar answer. I hope you don't mind my edit.

Comment: Yup, you beat me to it +1.  Darn time difference (5 am in Chgo).